# As much as Or as much or

Tags: grammaticality

> He feels his troubles as much or even more than they.

Is this grammatically correct or do I need to add "as much as"

Comment: I think the sentence itself was grammatically correct already

Comment: I'd add a second "as": "as much as or even more than they"  Without the second "as" the first of  the two alternatives indicated by "or" would be either "as much they" or "as much than they", neither of which is grammatical.

Comment: I think some people interpret "as much or even more" as a set phrase, with "than" applying to the whole comparison. Grammatically you probably need the extra "as", as @AndreasBlass says, but informally the first version works.

Comment: It will never be misunderstood but strictly *as much or (even) more than* is wrong. It should be *as much as or (even) more than*.